# Google maps v3, JSON, Objects and Opera

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, object, opera

I am using http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false to retrieve latitude and longitude for address.

While retrieving the data from google, I store the lats and lngs into arrays myLat and myLng.

The end user enters addresses into a textarea along with the names of the buildings which are also stored into their own arrarys schoolAddressArray and schoolNameArray.

I place the results in a div called results --

```
document.getElementById("results")
```

Then I take the constructed string and use eval to convert it into a "JSON like" object.

```
PHP start

global $browser;

if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Opera") !== FALSE)
{ 
    $browser = "opera";
}
if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "MSIE") !== FALSE)
{ 
    $browser = "msie";
}
if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Firefox") !== FALSE)
{ 
    $browser = "ff";
}
if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Safari") !== FALSE)
{ 
    $browser = "safari";
}
echo'
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var $whichBrowser = "'; echo $browser; echo'";
-->
</script>
';

PHP end
```

This is where the JavaScript starts

```
var strlen = tempVar.length;
var myNewTempVar = tempVar.slice(0,strlen-2)+']';
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = myNewTempVar;
if($whichBrowser == "msie")
{
    //alert(document.getElementById("results").childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    markers = window.eval(document.getElementById("results").childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
else if($whichBrowser == "opera")
{
    //markers = window.eval([getProperty(tempVar.slice(1,strlen-2))]);
    //alert(markers);
    //markers = [{ lat: 34.0878234, lng: -118.1543285, name: "1 school"}, { lat: 34.071239, lng: -118.1506133, name: "2 school"}, { lat: 34.1015362, lng: -118.1328816, name: "3 school"}, { lat: 34.098139499, lng: -118.1168382, name: "4 school"}, { lat: 34.0751855, lng: -118.1381771, name: "5 school"}, { lat: 34.0856624, lng: -118.1345840, name: "6 school"}, { lat: 34.0951319, lng: -118.1421722, name: "7 school"}, { lat: 34.0760016, lng: -118.1281349, name: "8 school"}, { lat: 34.0621694, lng: -118.1291052, name: "9 school"}, { lat: 34.0583261, lng: -118.1563075, name: "10 school"}, { lat: 34.046435, lng: -118.1524630, name: "11 school"}, { lat: 34.054128899, lng: -118.1280777, name: "12 school"}];
    for(var myX=0;myX<myLat.length;myX++)
    {
        markers.push(["{ lat: "+myLat[myX]+",  lng: "+myLng[myX]+",  name: "+schoolNameArray[myX]+"}"]);
    }
    alert(markers);
}
else
{
    markers = eval('('+myNewTempVar+')');
}
```

JavaScript End

As you can see, I use PHP's

```
strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

to figure out what browser is being used by the end user followed by echoing some javascript to set the variable $whichBrowser. This has worked for me since early 2000s -- BTW, I don't know what to call that. The 90s are the 90s. Are these the 10s? The 0s?

Anyways, the code for IE, FF and Safari work fine, but I have tried everything that I could think of with Opera and it just will not see markers as an object.

I have copied the constructed string from the results div and hard coded it to see if it worked at all in opera, which it does with no errors at all.

I have also tried:

```
for(index in myLat)
{
 markers[index].lat = myLat[index];
 markers[index].lng = myLng[index];
 markers[index].name = schoolNameArray[index];
}
```

I have received errors ranging from cannot convert markers[index] into an object to Uncaught exception: RangeError: Maximum recursion depth exceeded

Here is the test data that I am using:

```
2821 W. Commonwealth Ave., Alhambra, CA
2001 S. Elm St., Alhambra, CA
110 W. McLean St., Alhambra, CA
100 S. Granada Ave., Alhambra, CA
1603 S. Marguerita Ave., Alhambra, CA
409 S. Atlantic Blvd., Alhambra, CA
301 N. Marengo Ave., Alhambra, CA
509 W. Norwood Pl., Alhambra, CA
120 S. Ynez Ave., Monterey Park, CA
400 Casuda Canyon Dr., Monterey Park, CA
1701 Brightwood St., Monterey Park, CA
650 Grandridge Ave., Monterey Park, CA
```

Here's the link to my test server -- 
http://kronusproductions.com/mycarpaysme_ajax/test_street_view13.php

As you can see there are no errors reported in IE, Safari and FF, but Opera is a different ball game.

Some warnings in Safari for the svgs returned by google and some css warnings in FF, but 0 errors. IE complains when an address is not returned by google, but I will enter some kind of try and catch code for google after fixing this issue in Opera.

I have tried also sending the string to a function and return the evaluation, but nothing has worked so far.

Thanks in advance and I hope I have followed all the rules to posting to this forum.

Comment: Don't use `for(index in myLat)` on javascript arrays.  Also, using `eval` is almost always a good sign that you're doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
for(index in myLat){
 markers[index].lat = myLat[index];
 markers[index].lng = myLng[index];
 markers[index].name = schoolNameArray[index];
}
```

should be

```
for(var i=0;i<myLat.length;i++){
     markers.push({
        lat: myLat[i],
        lng: myLng[i],
        name: schoolNameArray[i]
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is beautiful. I have the maps currently working with the code that I have and the problem with Opera was that it was using the new line character from the textarea holding the user's names for schools. I placed a trim function on the schoolNameArray which removed the new line character. However, with that said, I believe this code is much better than mine and I will create test_street_view16.php to test it out. Thank very much. The link is -- http://kronusproductions.com/mycarpaysme_ajax/test_street_view16.php

Comment: OK, just tested it out and, in Safari, I am receiving an error of TypeError: Result of expression 'markers[0]' [undefined] is not an object.

Comment: Sorry, I am an idiot. I was having the object markers being set to tempObj and therefore I was overwriting markers with a null object. It works perfectly. Does anyone have a link to help me with finding an alternative address, should google not find an image (panorama) associated with the address? You know, like the closest address with a panorama. Reverse geocoding will bring me another address, but not necessarily produce another panorama.

Comment: choose an answer for this question, and start a new one.

Comment: I clicked on "Yes" for this answer, but I do not see that it has made a difference. How do I choose an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Any modern browser will have its own JSON parser:

```
JSON.parse('{"hello": ".jpg"}')
```

Use that and NOT `eval`

```
var points = {filled: false};
if(typeof(JSON) != undefined){
   points = JSON.parse(jsonString);
   points.filled = true;
}else{
   alert('Come back after you upgrade your janky old browser');
}
if(points.filled){//get the data you want here
```

No need for browser detection, either.  Well, unless you really want to get those IE6 users.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply:

When I try:
    for(var myX=0;myX<myLat.length;myX++)
  {
   markers = JSON.parse('{ "lat": '+myLat[myX]+',  "lng:" '+myLng[myX]+',  "name:" "'+schoolNameArray[myX]+'"}');
  }

Comment: Why are you making a string to make an object?

Comment: I am receiving -- Uncaught exception: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: Unescaped control char in string: "1

Comment: I am making a string into an object so that google maps can use the object for the dynamic markers being generated. All other browsers are working just fine. It is only Opera that I am having an issue with and, as a result, I am trying to give Opera an object to send to google.

Comment: Thanks for your help -- http://kronusproductions.com/mycarpaysme_ajax/test_street_view15.php -- I was also able to add the try and catch for IE's finding a null obj whenever google does not have a panorama for a particular location. Turns out the reason why my eval was working for the other browsers, was due to it ignoring the new line space which was being read from textareas. That was the unescaped control char. Now all browsers are using the same code JSON.parse and no more eval. Thanks once more